# Parse Add Exist Object to Table

Tags: angularjs, cordova, parse-platform

I started to use Parse.com for my first Cordova Application
I got a problem with Relation.
I have a table "Employee" contain all my employees.
And i have too a table "Expense", contain all expense of my employees.
Each expense will connect to one employee, and one employee can have many expenses.
So i created a column "ExpenseBy" in Expense table , type Pointer to table Employee.
But when i created a new expense, i can not add an exist employee to this field (ExpesnseBy). The Parse'systeme always create new employee.
Please help me !
Thank all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely due to how you are loading the employee. You simply have to first load the employee and then when you create the expense you set the `ExpenseBy` field to the employee:

```
var Employee = Parse.Object.extend("Employee");
var Expense = Parse.Object.extend("Expense");
var query = new Parse.Query(Employee);

query.get("xWMyZ4YEGZ", {
  success: function(employee) {
    var expense = new Expense();

    expense.set("ExpenseBy", employee);
    expense.save();
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});
```

More information is available from the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-pointers).